# Как работает протокол TCP/IP?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip

Привет.

Вопрос по сетям (стек протоколов *TCP*/*IP*). Если человек вводит *url*-адрес в строку адреса в браузере и жмет энтэр, то:

1. Браузер смотрит, а есть ли на компе в таблице соответствия доменных имен логическим адресам данное доменное имя. Например, его нет в таблице и отправляется *DNS*-пакет-запрос на *DNS*-сервер подсети... потом приходит ответ.
2. Айпи адрес получателя теперь известен и начинается установка соединения по протоколу *TCP* - трехкратное рукопожатие.

...

Мне не понятно, ГДЕ все эти правила записаны (где эта последовательность действий задана) - "посмотри, есть ли соответствие "доменное имя - айпи" на компе, если нет, отправь, днс-запрос серверу днс, жди ответ, потом устанавливай соединение по протоколу айпи, котом пакеты лови (хттп и тсп-пакеты) и посылай подтверждение о получении, закрывай соединение"? Это какой-то протокол? Везде пишут про ОПИСАННУЮ ВЫШЕ последовательность действий, но мне не понятно КАКАЯ ПРОГРАММА ЭТО ВСЕ ДЕЛАЕТ И ГДЕ ЭТО "ЗАШИТО".

Comment: Это выполняет драйвер tcp/ip в ядре операционной системы (это то что касается tcp/ip), а DNS частично библиотека языка, частично ядро, частично служба DNS

Comment: Поведение браузера не такое как описано в вопросе, но если основной вопрос, "ГДЕ правила для TCP/IP описаны", то [основное место где все официальные стандарты для интернета публикуются это различные RFCs](http://www.itprc.com/tcpipfaq/faq-1.htm#how-tcpip), хотя наверняка многие вещи только в виде кода (в основном внутри различных ОС) существует (могут быть и userspace реализации). Ну а чтобы ответить на вопрос в заголовке "как TCP/IP работает" помимо многочисленных RFCs, целые книги написаны такие как [TCP/IP Illustrated by W. Richard Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Illustrated)

Comment: jfs, что я написал неправильно в вопросе?

Comment: @Dimon к примеру, почитайте что [`getaddrinfo()`, предоставляемый системой](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html), делает (то что вы хотели в пункте №1 выразить)—результат может зависеть от номера порта и результат может быть списком возможных опций, которые можно использовать для соединения.

Answer (score 8):

**Работа с сетью** - это одна из частей многоуровневой системы ввода/вывода в операционной системе. Если вникать глубже, когда вы инициализируете запрос к устройству, этот запрос **обслуживает диспетчер ввода-вывода**, который передаст его куда нужно, и вернет в процесс данные, которые нужны от устройства.

Во всех современных сетях используется так называемый стек протоколов
для наслоения различных протоколов друг на друга. На каждом уровне решаются разные вопросы. Например, на самом **нижнем уровне** протоколы определяют, 
как сообщить в потоке битов, где начинаются и где заканчиваются пакеты. На **более высоком** уровне протоколы занимаются прокладыванием маршрутов для пакетов по сложным сетям от источника к месту назначения. **И на еще более высоком уровне** они обеспечивают надлежащую доставку всех пакетов в многопакетном сообщении в нужном порядке.

**Пользовательский процесс** генерирует сообщение и выдает системный вызов для его отправки по предварительно установленному TCP-соединению. Стек протоколов, **находящийся в ядре**, добавляет в начало сообщения TCP-заголовок, а затем IP-заголовок. Затем сообщение поступает к драйверу сети Ethernet, который добавляет **Ethernet-заголовок**, направляющий пакет к маршрутизатору в сети Ethernet. После чего этот маршрутизатор внедряет пакет в Интернет.

Чтобы **установить** соединение с удаленным хостом (или хотя бы отправить ему дейтаграмму), необходимо знать его IP-адрес. Поскольку оперировать списками 
с 32-битными адресами людям неудобно, была изобретена система под названием 
**DNS (Domain Name System — система доменных имен)**, представляющая собой базу данных, которая отображает ASCII-имена хостов на их IP-адреса.

1. Браузер запрашивает у DNS IP-адрес, соответствующий имени
2. DNS в ответ выдает IP
3. Браузер  устанавливает  TCP-соединение  с  портом  80  на  хосте  с  IP-адресом
4. Затем он отправляет запрос на файл index.html
5. Сервер отправляет файл index.html
6. Отображение файла
7. TCP-соединение разрывается.

Естественно, **установление соединения**, **запрос IP по имени** происходит через API операционной системы, операционная система пересылает ваш запрос DNS службе, которая сканирует файл hosts, и если там есть запись - выдает ее, иначе обращается к серверу или собственному кешу.

Рекомендую Вам почитать **"Современные операционные системы" Э. Таненбаум.**, книга большая, но знаний от нее получите по архитектуре и работе операционной системы массу.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. оценил

Comment: @Dimon Пожалуйста! Рекомендую Вам также почитать про модель OSI, она вам поможет в решении подобных вопросов.

Comment: @Dimon, наверное далее должна последовать серия вопросов про arp (это каким образом IP преобразуется в MAC) и роутинг (а это -- каким образом IP пакеты из моей локальной машины доходят до сервера, который где-то за океаном).